# Difference between ulimit, lsof, cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max

Tags: apache-kafka, centos, file-descriptor

I've been getting `java.io.IOException: Too many open files` while running a Kafka instance and using one topic with 1000 partitions so I started investigating the file descriptors limits in my ec2 vm. I cannot understand which is exactly the limit for open files on a Centos 7 machine since all the following commands produce different results. The commands are:

- `ulimit -a`: open files 1024
- `lsof | wc -l`: 298280
- `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`: 758881 (which is consistent with `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`)

If the actual limit is the one the last command produces then I am well below it (`lsof | wc -l`: 298280). But if this is the case, the output of the `ulimit` command is quite unclear to me since I am well above the 1024 open files.

[According to the official documentation the best way to check for file descriptors in Centos is the `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23389_01/doc.11116/e21036/perf002.htm) but are there all these seemingly "inconsistencies" between these commands?

Comment: Might be a better question for [unix.se]

Comment: The question was answered in the [Unix&Linux stack by Haxiel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476355/316495)